# Can a multiple systemd services be controlled through a single systemd timer?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

A `foo.service` service can be controlled by a `foo.timer`. Is it possible the make a single systemd timer controlling multiples systemd services?

Comment: Adding dependencies to `foo.service`? or else making a dedicated `foo.target` and then directing `foo.timer` to that target (`Unit=foo.target` directive in `[Target]` section)

Comment: @LL3 Could you elaborate in an answer, please.

Comment: Sorry for a typo: not `[Target]` section, `[Timer]` section in `foo.timer`. I haven't got enough spare time for a proper answer, but the general idea is to simply add your other services as `Wants` or `Requires` dependencies in your "main" `foo.service` (or `foo.target`). Those dependencies should pull-in your other services.